# Which mutex lock variant should I use in Linux kernel developing?

Tags: linux-kernel, mutex, semaphore

AFAIK, the mutex API was introduced to the kernel after LDD3 (Linux device drivers 3rd edition) was written so it's not described in the book.

The book describes how to use the kernel's semaphore API for mutex functionality.

It suggest to use `down_interruptable()` instead of `down()`:

> You do not, as a general rule,
>       want to use noninterruptible operations unless there truly is no alternative. Non-interruptible operations are a good way to create unkillable processes (the dreaded
>       “D state” seen in ps), and annoy your users [Linux Device Drivers 3rd ed]

**Now. here's my question:**

The mutex API has two "similar" functions:
`mutex_lock_killable()` an `mutex_lock_interruptable()`. Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `mutex_lock_interruptible()` function to allow your driver to be interrupted by *any* signal.
This implies that your system call should be written so that it can be restarted.
(Also see [ERESTARTSYS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576604/what-does-erestartsys-used-while-writing-linux-driver).)

Use `mutex_lock_killable()` to allow your driver to be interrupted *only* by signals that actually kill the process, i.e., when the process has no opportunity to look at the results of your system call, or even to try it again.

Use `mutex_lock()` when you can guarantee that the mutex will not be held for a long time.

Comment: Any idea why this variant (killable) doesn't exist on the semaphore API ?

Comment: Nobody has felt the need to implement this because semaphores aren't widely used.